# How to distinguish between left and right modifier keys

Tags: c++, qt, events, keyboard-events, ctrl

In Qt's `QKeyEvent`, I can check whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed by checking if `ev->key()` is `Qt::Key_Control`, but how can I distinguish between the left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys?

I also need the same thing for <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this using pure `Qt` methods, as far as I know.

Depending on your platform, however, you might be able to distinguish between the keys using the [`QKeyEvent::nativeScanCode()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qkeyevent.html#nativeScanCode) method instead of `QKeyEvent::key()`.

For example, on Windows you should be able to test which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key was pressed as follows:

```
if (event->nativeScanCode() == VK_LCONTROL) {
  // left control pressed
} else if (event->nativeScanCode() == VK_RCONTROL) {
  // right control pressed
}
```

Comment: So in Windows `nativeScanCode()` should return as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx Which probably Its not doing. So I think I need to distinguish between normal alpha/numbers and control keys. buts whats the generic function that tells this is an alpha/numeric key and this is an ALT/SHIFT/CTRL/BACK/..... key ?

Comment: @DiproSen: Just try testing against `VK_LCONTROL` etc.

Comment: really ? is it that easy ? I was just sitting idle thinking whether it will work or not. However is it bad to treat Left/right keys as same ?

Comment: @DiproSen: I haven't tested it but I believe it should work. And wdym, is it bad to treat left/right keys the same? There's nothing wrong with it, just depends on what you need in your application...

Answer (score 1):

Left and Right keys are part of virtual key code -> use `nativeVirtualKey()` to compare with windows `VK_*` enums instead of `nativescancode()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Qt Namespace Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html), the `enum Qt::Key` has a different value for `Qt::Key_Alt` and `Qt::Key_AltGr`.

However, `enum Qt::KeyboardModifier` and `enum Qt::Modifier` don't see the pair of keys as different modifiers.

*(note: I would have posted this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. yet)*

Answer (score 0):

If `VK_RCONTROL`does not work, check your nativeScanCode value of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd>:

`std::cout<<keyEvent->nativeScanCode();` and use this value:

```
int control_right = 285;
if(key->nativeScanCode() == control_right){...
```